# How to save jpegs of FITS files?

Tags: python, matplotlib

https://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/generated/examples/io/plot_fits-image.html#sphx-glr-generated-examples-io-plot-fits-image-py

I have a program that follows closely the link above and I want to saves the FITS matplotlib image as a jpeg file so when I work with my real FITS files later on, I can save them as `jpegs`.

I tried to save it the usual way:

```
plt.savefig("output.jpg")
```

However, after doing this, I find that the output does not look anything like the image
[![It is a completely blank image][1]][1]

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XNRlp.jpg

Comment: You shall normalize it. A fits file most probably has values ranging between `[0, 65535]` which is not values for `jpg` format. You can normalize the number between `[0, 1]` or `[0, 255]`. My sugesstion would be using `ZScaleInterval`: https://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/api/astropy.visualization.ZScaleInterval.html#astropy.visualization.ZScaleInterval

Comment: @MSH Thanks, but could you be more specific with how normalization works? Perhaps give an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So let's see:

### What is normalization?

> in the simplest cases, normalization of ratings means adjusting values measured on different scales to a notionally common scale, [see](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normalization_(statistics))

Let's say we have a number that must between a range. What would this number be if we change the range?

In your example, you have a 2D array. It contains some numbers. We do not precisely know what is the range of these numbers. But we know that for `jpg` format we need the numbers to be between `[0, 255]`.

#### The most basic way of normalization:

To normalize data between `[0, 1]` one can use:

```
normalized_data = (data - min_val) / (max_val - min_val)
```

using this formula you can change the range easily. Let's say you want to change the range between `[x, y]`:

```
normalized_data = ((data - min_val) / (max_val - min_val)) * (y - x) + x
```

Please notice `x<y`. Fun fact you can flip the color by doing `x>y`.

For a more generic way you can have your function as (considering your data is `numpy.ndarray`):

```
def normalize(data, lower=0, upper=255):
    return ((data - data.min()) / (data.max() - data.min())) * (upper - lower) + lower
```

Here you have your normalization function.

```
from astropy.io import fits


def normalize(data, lower=0, upper=255):
    return ((data - data.min()) / (data.max() - data.min())) * (upper - lower) + lower

data = fits.getdata("UITfuv2582gc.fits") # https://fits.gsfc.nasa.gov/samples/UITfuv2582gc.fits
print(data.min(), data.max())
normalized_data = normalize(data)
print(normalized_data.min(), normalized_data.max())
```

The return is:

```
-1.8528488e-15 4.218319e-13
0.0 255.0
```

You can easily see, that the values were distributed between `[-1.8528488e-15, 4.218319e-13]` but after normalization values are distributed between `[0.0, 255.0]`.

#### Some better way

Using your own normalization methods is reinventing the wheel. `astropy` already comes with these kinds of methods. One can find these methods under `Visualization` ([see](https://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/visualization/index.html)). And if you ever used [ds9](https://sites.google.com/cfa.harvard.edu/saoimageds9), you are already familiar with these functions.

#### TL;DR

An example for ZScale would be:

```
from astropy.visualization import ZScaleInterval
from astropy.io import fits
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt


data = fits.getdata("UITfuv2582gc.fits") # https://fits.gsfc.nasa.gov/samples/UITfuv2582gc.fits
zscale = ZScaleInterval()
plt.imshow(zscale(data), cmap="gray")
plt.savefig("asd.png")
plt.show()
```

Here is the result:
[image]